# Round up double

Tags: java

I´ve got different double values, e.g 2.71, 0.51, 4.02 and 1,52. 1,52 should get round up to 2, because its >= 0.02.

I tried it with the following function, but for 1,52 i got the wrong answer. I guess because of Math.round. I don´t now further steps.

```
 if (noOfLiters >= Math.round(noOfLiters) + limit) {            
    noOfLiters = noOfLiters * 2 + 1;        
 } 
 else {            
    noOfLiters = noOfLiters * 2;        
 }                
 return (int) noOfLiters;
```

Comment: So should 0.51 be rounded to 1 and 4.02 to 5?

Comment: When do you actually round it ever and set it to the value?  Right now you are just depending on the cast of the `int`, what is wrong with the value of 3 that it returns for 1.52?

Comment: Your logic seems not clear. can you re-thinking and writing?

Comment: Yeah. Thomas thats how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Ceiling to next higher double or int can be done like this:

```
//ceil to next higher double
double d1Ceiled = Math.ceil(d1);

//convert double to int
int d1CeiledInt = Double.valueOf(d1Ceiled).intValue();
```